# How do I import module in jupyter notebook directory into notebooks in lower directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, python-import, jupyter-notebook

I have used jupyter notebook for data analysis for quite sometime. I would like to develop a module in my jupyter notebook directory and be able to import that new module into notebooks. My jupyter notebook file directory can be represented as follows;

```
Jupyter notebooks\

    notebook1.ipynb

    new_module\
        __init__.py
        newfunction.py

    currentnotebooks\
        notebook2.ipynb
```

When use `import new_module` in notebook1.ipynb it works however when I try the same command in notebook2.ipynb I get the following `ImportError: No module named 'new_module'`. The two obvious solutions are A) move new_module into the currentnotebooks directory or B) move notebook2.ipynb up to the same level as new_module. I don't want to mess around with the file structure at all. Is this possible?

Comment: If you put `new_module` into one of the directories listed in `sys.path`, it will be importable from anywhere.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to make sure that the parent directory of `new_module` is on your python path.  For a notebook that is one level below `new_module`, this code will do the trick:

```
import os
import sys
nb_dir = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
if nb_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(nb_dir)
```

If you're further down in the directory hierarchy, you will need to adjust the way `nb_dir` is set, but that's all.  You should *not* run this code for a notebook in `Jupyter notebooks`, since it would add the parent of that directory to the python path, which is probably undesirable.

The reason the import works for `notebook1` is that sys.path contains `''` (the empty string), which is aways the current directory of the running interpreter (kernel, in this case).  A google search for `explain python path` turns up several good explanations of how python uses `PYTHONPATH` (aka `sys.path`).

Comment: So I always have to do your suggested boilerplate code before I can access other modules even if they are just one folder above? Is there no other proper way to achieve this, e.g. via relative imports? (though I must admit that I am still not sure about how relative imports work)

Comment: More or less.  The exception would be if the parent directory was a module as well (and so had an`__init__.py` file), but that seems both strange and unlikely to me.  Putting the notebook directory in `PYTHONPATH` would avoid the need to add it to sys.path this way.